# ember vendor js file does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to work an admin theme into an ember project. There is a custom.js file that has a lot of the javascript for the sidebar, header stuff etc. I have it in the vendor folder vendor/custom.js. I am including it in ember-cli-build as app.import('vendor/custom.js'); When I look in chrome at the vendor.js file I see the contents listed in it, but the javascript on the page does not work.

If I take some of the sections out of the custom.js and put them in the hbs file within  tags the do run and work. I'm wondering why just including importing the file doesn't work.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Here is a link to the custom.js file [Custom.js Gist](https://gist.github.com/spacerobotTR/bd6aba4f1c53490a89db4acb7a60e03a)

Comment: There is no reason for your Custom.js File. Just write your own Components and put your custom js in `didInsertElement` etc.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to all this. Can you describe a little more about what you mean? Or if there is a link information on this that would be helpful.

Comment: And where would I put this? In a route or controller? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to include customjs from the admin theme into your app.
Instead of including the custom.js directly, create custom components for each admin-theme component.

In your component you can register you click-event handler and you jquery custom code. There is a old blog post from a core team member acout this.

http://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-initialize-a-jquery-component-with-ember-js/

But i think you need some basic knowledge about how ember is rendering and what a component is compared to a controller + template. You also need to understand what the admintheme js is trying to achieve.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! Got it all working now. So when I heard component I kept thinking of HBS components within templates. I forgot there were app/components ha. Once I hooked everything up in there it's all working now. I appreciate the help!